# PLSQL Need to match up nested records

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table with records showing when an item is put on hold or released.
Nested holds are possible. Some records have become mixed up, new logic is needed.
To fix this I need to match the release to the hold - I have a roughly drawn example below - the id column doesn't exist but is what I need to generate.

[image: Example data]

The table I'm working from has no unique identifier I can use and nothing to match the release to the hold except the order they happen in.
I've been playing with this for a while and can't nail it down.

The problem comes when I get 2 or more hold sin a row without a release. If we have hold1, hold2 and hold3 then the releases after this should be read in the order release3, release2, release1.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE "TBL_ACTIONS" 
   ("ITEM_ID" CHAR(5 BYTE), 
    "ACTION_DATE" DATE, 
    "ACTION" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)
   );

Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('19/11/16 01:00:28','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('19/11/16 01:12:45','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('19/11/16 16:00:19','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('19/11/16 16:12:40','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('20/11/16 14:52:42','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('20/11/16 16:00:10','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('24/11/16 17:52:49','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('24/11/16 21:12:40','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('24/11/16 23:12:48','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('24/11/16 23:32:39','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('28/11/16 14:40:17','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('28/11/16 14:40:18','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('28/11/16 19:12:40','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('29/11/16 08:17:59','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('29/11/16 08:17:59','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('29/11/16 08:18:40','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('29/11/16 08:18:40','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('01/12/16 11:03:39','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('02/12/16 08:10:51','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('02/12/16 11:27:06','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('02/12/16 11:27:11','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('03/12/16 07:10:07','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('03/12/16 07:10:07','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('16/12/16 14:37:39','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('16/12/16 14:37:40','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('22/12/16 12:20:52','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('22/12/16 12:20:52','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('22/12/16 12:29:39','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('22/12/16 12:29:39','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('06/01/17 10:23:47','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('06/01/17 10:23:48','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('06/01/17 11:52:26','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('06/01/17 11:52:26','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('09/01/17 13:47:52','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('09/01/17 13:47:59','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('25/01/17 09:42:35','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('25/01/17 09:42:35','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('31/01/17 12:11:24','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('31/01/17 12:11:31','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('31/01/17 12:12:20','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('31/01/17 12:12:28','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('02/02/17 09:01:48','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('02/02/17 09:01:48','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('02/02/17 09:02:58','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('02/02/17 09:02:58','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('06/02/17 16:57:47','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('06/02/17 16:57:47','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('07/02/17 16:56:39','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('07/02/17 16:56:47','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('07/02/17 16:57:12','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('07/02/17 16:57:21','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('08/02/17 16:41:54','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('08/02/17 16:41:54','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('08/02/17 17:21:53','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('08/02/17 17:22:04','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('09/02/17 16:38:35','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('09/02/17 16:38:43','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('10/02/17 07:40:05','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('10/02/17 07:40:13','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('10/02/17 23:31:52','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('10/02/17 23:31:52','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('11/02/17 09:16:22','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('11/02/17 09:16:23','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('17/02/17 16:48:13','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('17/02/17 16:48:13','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('17/02/17 16:49:16','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('17/02/17 16:49:17','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('21/02/17 15:42:40','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('21/02/17 17:25:08','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('21/02/17 17:25:09','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('21/02/17 17:25:18','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('21/02/17 17:25:18','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('27/02/17 16:51:39','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('27/02/17 16:51:39','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('27/02/17 16:51:46','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('27/02/17 16:51:46','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('28/02/17 14:06:59','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('28/02/17 14:06:59','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('28/02/17 14:07:10','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('28/02/17 14:07:10','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('03/03/17 10:04:08','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('03/03/17 10:04:08','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('03/03/17 10:04:09','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('03/03/17 10:04:09','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('03/03/17 10:23:27','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('03/03/17 10:23:27','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('03/03/17 10:23:27','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('03/03/17 10:23:27','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('03/03/17 10:55:55','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('03/03/17 10:55:55','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('03/03/17 10:55:55','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('03/03/17 10:55:55','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('06/03/17 13:23:25','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('06/03/17 13:23:25','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('06/03/17 13:23:26','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('06/03/17 13:23:26','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('06/03/17 15:07:20','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('06/03/17 15:10:09','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('08/03/17 15:35:45','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('10/03/17 12:17:36','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('10/03/17 12:17:37','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('10/03/17 13:22:47','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('10/03/17 13:22:55','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('10/03/17 13:23:20','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('10/03/17 13:23:27','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('18/03/17 07:12:27','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('18/03/17 07:12:28','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('30/03/17 16:17:54','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('30/03/17 17:52:44','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('30/03/17 18:12:49','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('30/03/17 23:32:45','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('01/04/17 20:32:34','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('02/04/17 19:53:43','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('02/04/17 20:52:44','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('04/04/17 21:39:18','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('04/04/17 21:45:23','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('05/04/17 20:54:49','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('05/04/17 21:00:19','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('10/04/17 17:35:13','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('17/04/17 11:29:33','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('17/04/17 21:32:44','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('18/04/17 00:40:12','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('23/04/17 09:20:35','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('23/04/17 10:52:41','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('25/04/17 20:40:50','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('25/04/17 20:52:47','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('28/04/17 01:13:17','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('28/04/17 04:32:35','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('30/04/17 16:12:47','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('30/04/17 16:20:08','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('30/04/17 16:40:32','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('30/04/17 18:20:19','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('01/05/17 03:12:06','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('17/05/17 16:58:17','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('17/05/17 16:58:17','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('19/05/17 15:10:28','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('19/05/17 15:10:28','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('28/05/17 21:14:06','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('30/05/17 15:41:58','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('31/05/17 10:05:00','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('31/05/17 10:05:11','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('31/05/17 10:05:17','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('31/05/17 10:05:27','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('02/06/17 00:30:22','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Release');
    Insert into TBL_ACTIONS (ITEM_ID,ACTION_DATE,ACTION) values ('ITEM1',to_date('04/06/17 06:43:33','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),'Hold');
```

Comment: Hi Gerard - it's pretty hard to follow exactly what you're after.  Is there any chance you could provide table creation scripts, and sample data.  Then you need to be clear about the logic you want to apply.  With these you'll stand a better chance of getting a decent answer.

Comment: Hi,Yeah ill try and put something together. It's difficult to explain, not sure of the right terms to use. I need to match every release to the correct hold. The problem lies when 2 or more holds are created in a row.

Comment: Thanks Gerard.  Different oracle versions have different tools that could apply here.  Can you include your oracle version?  Thanks

Comment: I think I understand what you want, but I'm curious about the ordering of the existing data. Is it simply ordered by `Item` and then `Date`?

Comment: Hi Steve, there is also a sequence number unique for each row. I should have included that. Trying to get a good example into a test table but its a bit tricky. I think it will have to use some kind of cursor for this and go row by row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments, I've assumed you have an ID column which can be used for ordering. I imagine there may be more efficient ways to do the following (I'd search for Last-In, First-Out or LIFO), but I wanted to see what I could come up with under my own steam:

```
With PushPop as (
select
    nh1.Id,
    nh1.Activity,
    sum(case when nh2.Activity = 'Release' then -1 else 1 end) as PushPop
from
    NestedHolds nh1
    LEFT JOIN NestedHolds nh2 ON
        nh1.Id >= nh2.Id
group by
    nh1.Id,
    nh1.Activity
order by
    nh1.id
)

SELECT
nh.*,
NewIDs.NewID
from
NestedHolds nh
JOIN
(
SELECT 
    a.Id HoldId,
    min(b.Id) as ReleaseId,
    row_number() over (order by a.Id) NewID
FROM
    PushPop a
    JOIN PushPop b ON
        a.Id < b.Id
        AND a.PushPop = b.PushPop + 1 
WHERE
a.Activity = 'Hold'
AND b.Activity = 'Release'
GROUP BY
    a.Id
order by
a.Id
) NewIDs on nh.Id in (NewIDs.HoldID, NewIDs.ReleaseID)
order by nh.id
;
```

Comment: Steve this looks great, just run the select and it looks great. Gonna use this to update my data.
I really appreciate your help - thanks.

Comment: Awesome. By way of a thank you, and to help other users find useful content, could you mark my answer as accepted (and upvote if possible)?. I enjoyed working on this question, and actually my own searches for "LIFO" stuff mostly turned up less useful stuff.

Comment: Done. Score hasn't changed - my reputation is too low :( like trying to pull in a nightclub